# Is this schema with nested subdocuments killing performance?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am building a turn-based browser-based RPG and have constructed a data model exemplified below. When a player engages in combat, both reads and writes will be performed 'souls' and 'items' subdocument (arrays) and further reads on the 'skills' and 'character' subdocument. I imagine each of these arrays to sporn between 1-30 subdocuments each

I have tried to contain pretty much all logic in a single collection for performance, but have I gone too far with the nesting?

I've heard that MongoDB/MeteorJS sports poor performance when using nested arrays, and would like to get some opinions on whether this data model is viable?

```
    email: 'a@test'
    password: 'f321'
    profile:
      character: 
        _id: 'c001'
        location: 'Isenheim'
        name: 'Ugyr'
        race: 'human'
        level: 1
        experience: 1
        maxHealth: 10
        curHealth: 10
        curAp: 10
        maxAp: 10
        flagged: false
        gold: 0
        souls: [
          _id: 'S001'
          name: 'Hound'
          race: 'beast'
          cost: 5
          active: false
          maxHealth: 5
          curHealth: 5
          maxAp: 6
          curAp: 6
          skills: [
            name: 'Bite'
            damage: 1
            cost: 2
          ,
            name: 'Shred'
            damage: 2
            cost: 4
            effects: 
              name: 'Bleeding'
              duration: 2
              type: 'subtractive'
              stats: ['curHealth']
              value: 1
          ]
        ]
        skills: [
          name: 'Slash'
          type: 'direct'
          damage: 2
          cost: 2
        ,
          name: 'Pierce'
          type: 'direct'
          damage: 3
          cost: 3
        ,
          name: 'Throwing Knives'
          type: 'direct'
          damage: 1
          cost: 1
        ]
        items: 
          equiped: 
            weapon:
              name: 'Rusty Knife' 
              attack: 2
            shield: null

          inventory: [
            name: 'Potion'
            type: 'consumable'
            effects:
              type: 'additive'
              stats: ['curHealth', 'curAp']
              value: 3
            amount: 500
          ,
            name: 'Minor Soul Stone'
            type: 'consumable'
            amount: 500
            effects: [
              type: 'additive'
              stats: ['curAp']
              value: 2
            ,
              type: 'subtractive'
              stats: ['curHealth']
              value: 1
            ]
          ,
            name: 'Health Potion'
            type: 'consumable'
            amount: 100
            effects: [
              type: 'additive'
              stackable: false
              stats: ['curHealth']
              value: 1
              duration: 2
            ]
          ]
          conditions: [

          ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have gone too far with nesting.

Meteor *DDP only sends changes/diffs for first level properties*. So any changes to `souls` & `items` will equate to the whole `profile` being sent again.

I would suggest breaking out `character` into a separate collection, along with `souls` and `items`.

Then, denormalise `userId` on to all of these and publish them in one go, eg:

```
Meteor.publish("my-characters",function(){
  if (this.userId == null){
    return;
  }
  return [
    characters.find({"userId": this.userId}),
    characterSouls.find({"userId": this.userId}),
    characterItems.find({"userId": this.userId})
  ];
});
```

This will likely give the best performance in terms of publishing cursors & data-on-the-wire.

Also, don't forget to index on `userId`:

```
characters._ensureIndex({userId: 1});
characterSouls._ensureIndex({userId: 1});
characterItems._ensureIndex({userId: 1});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Ill be able to normalize the items collection because it should only be around 500 documents at most, but each character may have between 1-20 unique souls, so this means that the soul collection will be very large and potentially cause a performance issues when joining documents?

Comment: When would you need to join? if you add the `userId` field (as per the example) then you can publish without using any joins. If you're worried about client side performance, 20 should be minimal

Comment: Ah I was confused, my bad, but do you think this data model would be scaleable to potentially support 1000+ concurrent users, with around 500 requests/second being sent to the server?

Comment: much more so than your current model; final results will vary on a lot of factors though